# R: Weighting calculation getting invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Tags: r, dplyr, weighted-average

I have the following data set:

```
    Date                 sector Forward TRT1Y USD CIQ MKVAL
  (time)                 (fctr)             (dbl)     (dbl)
1 1999-09-30 Consumer Discretionary        0.11622590 19856.182
2 1999-09-30            Industrials       -0.13436770     0.000
3 1999-09-30            Industrials        0.09085045     0.000
4 1999-09-30             Financials        0.69653463  6142.963
5 1999-09-30 Consumer Discretionary        0.00000000     0.000
6 1999-09-30             Financials        1.61538458  1510.159
7 1999-09-30             Financials        0.27569774     0.000
8 1999-09-30            Industrials       -0.33099464     0.000
9 1999-09-30 Consumer Discretionary        0.38051024 61308.492
10 1999-09-30           Industrials        0.07535502     0.000
```

Dates are quarterly and go up until 12/31/15.  Also, here is the structure:

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   97136 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Date             : POSIXct, format: "1999-09-30" "1999-09-30" "1999-09-30" 
 $ sector           : Factor w/ 11 levels "Consumer Discretionary",..: 8 6 7 4 
 $ Forward TRT1Y USD: num  0.1162 -0.1344 0.0909 0.6965 0 ...
 $ CIQ MKVAL        : num  19856 0 0 6143 0 ...
```

I'm trying to create a weight column based on 'CIQ MKVAL' and would like it to do the weighting by date and by sector.  The weight will then help me derive a weighted average forward TRT1Y for each sector and by each date.  Here is the weight function:

```
weight <- function(x) x/sum(x)
```

This is the code I'm using to find the weighting and splitting the data frame by date and sector

```
ddply(wMean1, .(Date,sector), transform, w=weight('CIQ MKVAL'))
```

But, when I'm running the code, I get the following error:

```
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

I have found something at this site:  http://www.r-bloggers.com/type-conversion-and-you-or-and-r/ that I believe says that when doing the above calculation it's converting my numeric fields to characters.  I am fairly new to R and I haven't figured out a way around this.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Please share your data, output of `str()` is of not much use.

Comment: The error message seems reasonably clear. 'CIQ MKVAL' is a character object and it makes no sense to either take a sum of a character value or divide it by some value.

Comment: In other words, you need to remove the quotes from around `'CIQ MKVAL'`.

Comment: Wow.  I guess I just assumed I was passing in a numeric column so it didn't matter what the column name was.  Thanks for helping out a struggling beginner.  I appreciate it.